# Farseer for platformer - (Almost) constant velocity

Tags: monogame, farseer-physics-engine

I am building the prototype for a platformer and would like to use farseer physics engine. I got the feedback that it might not be a good idea to use physics engine, but I would like to have elements like bumpers and so on.

At the moment I am looking for a good way for moving right and left (jumping is very easy). The goal is to get an almost constant velocity, so I was playing around with hight gravity and high linear damping and it is working fine, but also affects gravity. Is there a way to get a linear damping on the x-axis only or do I just have to increase gravity (which sounds a little bit strange to me).

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but I think a physics is a little bit too much for your needs. You should consider coding your movement from scratch. Bumpers(if I understand the behavior correctly) should not be that hard to implement. Just play around with the velocity of your player :-)

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but there are so much game elements like moving platforms, collision detection for complex objects, bumpers, ice and so on, that can be handled by a physics engine.